# Reshus Horabim Today?

Tags: halacha-theory, geography, modern-times, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

The most lenient shita for a reshus horabim i have ever heard of is that 600,000 people must pass on the road EVERY day.

Do any roads with daily CAPACITY for 600,000 people exist today?

Do any roads actualy fulfill this shita - have 600,000 people pass everyday? Without counting cars?

I am not asking about any other one of the requierments for a reshus horabim, just for roads that have the capacity/travel of 600,000 people.

Comment: Are you counting people in cars? Do the roads have to be perfectly straight?

Comment: Yes im counting cars, No the question has nothing to with straightness

Comment: I-10? I-95? I-5? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan-American_Highway

Comment: Actually, it's not clear people in cars should be counted.

Comment: I fail to see how this question is on topic. The relationship between the question and the applicability of halakhah is taken off the table. One doesn't need to know whether there are 2 such streets on the whole planet or 2 million to understand any of Judaism.

Comment: @MichaBerger It's asking about a specific criterion, even if others have different criteria, and helps us understand that opinion which is as much a part of Judaism as the other differing opinions. Would an answer saying "The Ramban rejected 600K being relevant" work? I think not. The number of opinions in Judaism which are _universally_ held are few and far between. People are certainly allowed to ask according to any of the other opinions out there if they want.

Comment: @MichaBerger I want to understand how big of a road the shita would need and from that be able to deduce which other roads deffinitly do not me his criteria

Comment: @SamuelManuel I encourage you to not use the formula "Edit: XYZ" and just rewrite the post to make sure it asks what you intend to clearly and precisely.

Comment: @MichaBerger regarding your answer, it can be that the 600,000 rule is derived from the chiluk if there is a Reshus HaRabim in the desert nowadays

Comment: @ShmuelBrin: My answer a"h focused on the textual source of the rule, how do we know chazal had it. You're giving a conceptual source, the shoresh of the rule (as the Chinukh would put it). The Ramban rejected Rashi's mention of 60 myriad because he did not believe it came from Chazal. I believe came from a statement by Ulla in a version of the gemara that only reached Ashkenaz (and apparently, the geonim).

Totally off topic, but related to the distinction I just made.... In the Bavli, "Mai ta'amah?" is answered with a reason for a ruling. In the Yerushalmi, the answer is a verse in Tanakh.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't understand your response to Micha. How is this question different than "I heard yams are Kosher. Where can I get yams?"

Comment: @Yez More like: Does [a certain Halachicly relevant situation] exist today? That's "general knowledge as it relates to Judaism", no? Incidentally, Micha's claim that whether there are 2 or 2 million doesn't help us understand Judaism, isn't necessarily true, if you have in mind a goal of how many there should be (eg. one could require of an opinion that many RHR existed in the time of Chazal and that's why they made so many enactments and talked about it like it was reality).

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm just not sure why experts in Judaism would be more likely to know this information. Maybe travel.se

Answer (score 3):

I guess one is the roads by meka

Since for the hajj millions of people come to one place in one day

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23487)

Comment: @sabbahillel Does it not answer Do any roads with daily CAPACITY for 600,000 people exist today?

Answer (score 0):

I was told that major boulevards such as Fifth Avenue in New York can be counted as a reshus harabim.

If we only count foot traffic, look here: [link](http://cityroom.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/12/06/you-like-walking-in-the-city-so-do-plenty-of-others/)
Now just add the cars and we should be set.

Comment: How about the Cross Bronx Expy/GW Bridge even just during Rush Hours? They most likely do it....

Comment: The GWB only has 280,000 vehicles a day including >1000 buses (http://www.nyc.gov/html/dot/downloads/pdf/nyc-bridge-traffic-report-2014.pdf page 220-223)

Comment: @SamuelManuel So what is the assumed average passengers per vehicle? considering we're dealing with buses and HOV, a 2:1 ratio isn't unreasonable...